# cakephp 2.x Shell using app Controller?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I want a shell script I've got to be able to access appController, is this possible, without copying that code into the AppShell ?  If so any pointers ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, shells shouldn't rely on code inside a controller, some pointers (as requested):

- If the Shell has to perform data-related tasks, move the code to the Model. This is good practice in any case (look up 'Skinny Controllers, Fat Models' on Google)
- Although not 'standard' supported, you can move the code to a 'Component' (see [Components](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/components.html)). Components are meant for re-usable portions of code used in Controllers.

If the above options really aren't an option, you will have to manually initialise the AppController. **keep in mind** that, because you're running from the command line, various things will **not be present**, e.g. There will be no 'request' and some environment variables (e.g. host name) may not return the expected value!

#### Manually initialising a Controller

Manually initialising the controller will be something like this;

```
App::uses('CakeRequest', 'Network');
App::uses('CakeResponse', 'Network');
App::uses('Controller', 'Controller');
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');

// request/response may be optional, depends on your use
$controller = new AppController(new CakeRequest(), new CakeResponse());
$controller->constructClasses();
$controller->startupProcess();
```

Comment: Also, if you add methods to your controller, they might be accessible through Cake's (auto)-routing, whereas in certain use cases, this is not desirable.